# B&R how to compile the program so as to not share source code with third parties

Tags: plc, br-automation-studio

I'm new to the B&R plc programming. I'm looking to find out if there is a way to compile a B&R automation studio program for an X90 mobile plc so that we could share this compiled program with the manufacturer of our machines to install the right software on each plc, without having to share the source code with them. Is that even possible and if so how can I do that?

Thank you for your support.

I've been looking around in the available B&R documentation and online but I don't seem to find anything useful.